# Restrict cursor to a UI Element in Silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight

I am working on a silverlight application that has to capture electronic signature from user as a part of it's functionality. I was able to build a PoC based on Silverlight Ink Presenter control, when the page renders I have designated a rectangular region into which user has to input his signature.

This absolutely works like a charm, but, I wsa not able to restrict pointing device to rectangular region so it can currently go out of the region irritating the user. User has to get it back to the rectangular region to input his signature. I would like to know if there is a way to restrict cursor to a rectangular region of the web page.

Something similar to "Cursor.Clip" of Windows.Forms

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Probably not due to security reasons, at least not without elevated privileges.

Comment: Thanks Tim, I am fine elevating privileges to achieve this. Please provide more inputs on the steps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try designing your own cursor as the pointer enters the region and hide the pointer. Set the bounds of the custom cursor to stay with int rectangle

here's a link for custom cursor

[custom cursor](http://www.gigyonline.com/code/source/silverlight/CustomMouseCursor.html)

Only problem is as you move it along with the mouse pointer then mouse pointer can move out but this cursor wont. Rest of the code you need to modify  so that user sticks to the particular edges